# Haystack incompatible with Django 1.4?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I just upgradated my django to 1.4. I am getting trouble with haystack app. Also, I tried to update haystack to last stable version but I still having problems. Does anyone had theses errors? How can I solve it?

I am getting the following errors.

When I access any page:

```
cannot import name MAX_SHOW_ALL_ALLOWED haystack\admin.py in <module>, line 2
```

and

```
# python manage.py rebuild_index
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing template source loader
django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source:
    "'module' object has no attri bute 'load_template_source'"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is a problem in haystack/admin.py file. Try to do the following:

1. remove import for `MAX_SHOW_ALL_ALLOWED`
2. before class `SearchChangeList` add method:

   ```
   def list_max_show_all(changelist):
       """
       Returns the maximum amount of results a changelist can have for the
       "Show all" link to be displayed in a manner compatible with both Django
       1.4 and 1.3. See Django ticket #15997 for details.
       """
       try:
           # This import is available in Django 1.3 and below
           from django.contrib.admin.views.main import MAX_SHOW_ALL_ALLOWED
           return MAX_SHOW_ALL_ALLOWED
       except ImportError:
           return changelist.list_max_show_all
   ```
3. in `SearchChangeList.get_results()` change `can_show_all` to

   ```
   can_show_all = result_count <= list_max_show_all(self)
   ```

Check [this thread](https://github.com/ixc/django-haystack/commit/5f24d058beb8ccbbf19b99932180c5c936f7c2c2) for more background info on the issue.

Comment: This requires modifying haystack though :(

Comment: But the link I put in the answer is the fork with this solution.

Comment: Thats a pity that this code still in the branch (wasnt commited to last release).

Comment: @szaman Forks are for submitting pull requests for fixes most of the time, not for using in a production environment. That is a problem for projects that cannot afford to use modified/forked versions of 3rd party modules. Hopefully v2.7 will be released soon.

Comment: Note that this change is included in Haystack 1.2.7.